# We're out of + noun

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Is the noun following "we're out of" a singular or plural?

For example we're out of apple or apples.

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the item is a countable noun.

- We're out of apple**s**.
- We're out of flour.
- Yes, we have no banana**s**.
- There is no Joy in Mudville, but they might have Ajax.

Comment: (in case its not clear the line "yes we have no bananas" is a joke, It's from a song about a Greek shopkeeper who "you should hear him speak!//
When you ask him anything, he never answers "no".//
He just "yes"es you to death...")

Comment: I'm not sure how "it depends" exactly, since uncountable nouns don't really have plural forms.

Comment: @stangdon, not true: fishes (multiple species), waters (as in meeting of the waters), flours (wheat and rye flours)...